# Security Concerns for VMs in DMZ

Tags: nat, vmware-workstation, dmz, guest-additions, virtual-network

In Vmware Workstation a VMnet8(NAT) Interface on Host System acts as a External Port for a VM Guest, If a Put the VM in DMZ can the Host get compromised or attacked as the VMnet8 has Ip addresses assigned to it from the Vmware Nat Service...? I have noticed even network shares get accessible from the IPs of these interfaces... ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a proper DMZ, and you are using NAT for the VM connection, so I'd say yes, this is a big concern. it sounds like you are not exposing the guest directly, you are exposing the host, and with it the guest via NAT.

Comment: I have actually planned on a sophos utm in dmz ...I'm making a vm for the same so how do I put a vm in dmz ... doesn't the nat on VMware have a firewall..

Comment: first NAT != firewall. second, VMNet8 interface is on your virtual network, not your physical one, so the IP address assigned to your host interface is used to connect to your VM as well. the router DMZ configuration forwards unsolicited traffic coming in on your WAN to the IP address in question, which is your Hosts interface, and has all the services your host provides bound to it (including the VMware virtual adapter). if you want to take the host out of the equation, use a bridged adapter, so that your VM exposes its own IP address and doesn't share the hosts.

Comment: Also note, that if you are using a consumer grade router, the DMZ feature can't really be made safe, especially when using a VM. A true DMZ has firewalls on both sides, one protecting against traffic coming in on the WAN, and another firewall between the DMZ systems and the rest of the internal network. in your case since its a VM, its difficult to put a firewall between the guest and the host (and the other LAN systems the host is adjascent to). You can probably set up a proper configuration using an enterprise router that supports multiple (more than 2) networks however.

Comment: Yes ...I got this...